# How to determine what battery to use?

Tags: voltage, batteries, voltage-regulator, battery-operated

I am making a project that requires two different voltage levels, 5V and 12V (although this can be lowered to 7V minimum). I have two voltage regulators as described by the schematics below:
[image: 12V regulator][image: 5V regulator]

I want to have one power source that can supply enough current and last a decent amount of time to power both regulator circuits. I was thinking single A batteries in series but I'm not sure how many would be sufficient because the input for each says `3-40V`, so technically I can get away with just two batteries in series or maybe two sets of two in series and those sets in parallel to get longer battery length. Or is a rechargeable battery better? The problem I'm having is I am not aware of a way to figure out what works and why because of my elementary electronics knowledge.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the power requirement of the load? Then include losses of the supply circuits and work out the time the device is on in hours. That should give you what you need to supply from the battery - then select a suitable battery mercury, nimh, lead acid etc etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The LM317 is a linear regulator, which means the output voltage is always lower than the input voltage. As the 317 is quite old, it's at least 3 V lower than the input voltage.

The diagrams say '3-40 V' on the input. That's the rating for the LM317s, not the ratings for the circuits as shown. The 12 V circuit should say '15-40 V' on the input, the 5 V circuit '8-40 V'.

Your comment about using two A batteries suggests you were hoping that these were boost converters. It also suggests you are a long way from designing anything starting from components.

In which case, although knowing nothing about your loads, you may want to consider this as a starting point. Use a 5 V 'powerbank' as your single 'battery', and the supply to your 5 V load. They are easy to charge (usually from USB), have constant voltage out, and they are protected from all sorts of over- and under- abuse. Buy a 5 V to 12 V boost converter module from one of the online retailers, and use it to power your 12 V load.

If this isn't suitable, then we need to know more about your loads, application, and other constraints.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was hoping to have a circuit all in one pcb but you are right, but I am pretty far away from designing it (or understanding it) myself. I got those schematics from some built in design blocks in Eagle CAD, and the input looked promising so I figured I would ask and see, so thanks for letting me know they aren't boost converters! I guess I will just stick with a power bank to make my life easier. Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

Those are linear voltage regulator circuits, and as mentioned, the LM317 is an old, old design with high drop out.

Even if you use low-dropout regulators, a linear regulator still works by "burning up" the excess energy -- the input current is always at least as much as the output current, so any voltage drop in the regulator has to be dissipated as heat.

So, first, for efficiency, you want to use switching regulators.  Expect between 80% and 95% efficiency.  You can get these as modules that fit the same spot as an LM780x regulator (which is similar to the LM317, but has a different pinout).  They're about as easy to use as an LM317, which is good -- at your level of expertise you don't want to build a switcher from the component level.

Second, if you're going to run from batteries, pay attention to the *real* end voltage -- "1.5V" cells usually have useful charge down to about 1V or 0.9V per cell.

Third, if you use a "buck" regulator you need at least a bit more voltage input than output.  If you use a "boost" regulator, you need *less* input voltage than output voltage.  If you can find a "buck-boost" module, the input voltage can range around quite a bit (but I don't know if they're available yet -- the chips haven't been out all that long).

At worst you'll only find buck regulators, and you'll need a 12-cell pack (eek!).  At best -- assuming your total power requirements are within the capabilities of your battery pack -- you can use two or four AA cells.